# Correct way to pass a variable from the server backend to javascript?

Tags: javascript, standards, unobtrusive-javascript

I need to pass a variable that php is aware of to my javascript code and I'm wondering what the *correct* way to do this is.

I already know that I could add this to the page generation:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
var someJSVariable = <?php echo $somePHPVariable ?>
</script>
```

But I find this method to be more obtrusive than I'd like. I am wondering if there is a *better* way to do this, or am I stuck with having to just inject inline javascript code in to the view script?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's just 1 variable, I think this is the best solution. If you don't want to mix in JS into your normal view, make a separate view which will be rendered as .js file and then just include a link to that .js in your "real" view. If you need performance, some smart catching would be needed there.

If there's more then 1 variable, for example a data exchange between html document and server you could use [AJAX](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_(programming)).

Answer (score 1):

I love [`json_encode()`](http://www.php.net/json_encode) for this kind of thing.

But yes, you are "stuck" with this inline approach. Honestly, would you prefer this?

```
$js = '<script type="text/javascript">';
$js .= "var someJSVariable = " . $somePHPVariable;
$js .= '</script>';

// some time later
echo $js;
```

Didn't think so. The inline approach is php's bread and butter. Go with it.

Answer (score 0):

You can always make an asynchronous request to a separate URL to get the dynamic value. But, you will take a slight performance penalty there as the page loads. With that in mind, I would recommend the in-line method you outlined.

You could also include another "js" file that's really a PHP page that's generating a bunch of javascript constants that you can then access in your main page.